# Increase coverage for void functions where on else branch is just a print and no variables changed

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I had to test a function similar with **foo()**:

```
class A{

.....  

void foo(int a)
{
        if( nullptr != m_member_name)
                m_member_mane->another_function();

        else Logger << "some message";
}

.....
Member_name *m_member_name;

}//end class A
```

In order to have branch coverage I think that I should make one test for *m_member_name != nullptr* and one for *m_member_name == nullptr*.

For the first is easy, because I expect that **another_function()** is called once, using

```
EXPECT_CALL(MOCK_Member_name, another_function())  
         .Times(1); // I created a mock for Member_name before
```

Where MOCK_Member_name is a mock for Member_name

But how should I verify if for m_member_name == nullptr is going on else branch?

I know that is a silly question, but I've only been studying Google Mock for a short time.

Comment: `Logger <<` is also just calling a function so you can do the same, no?

Comment: @idclev463035818   It should work, I guess. Logger is a very ugly class where is overwritten << operatror. And another thing, if in else is just a comment _//nothing to do_? Should I consider that I have a good line coverage?

Comment: I dont know gmock either, but instead of mocking only one method of `Logger` maybe it is easier to mock the whole `Logger`. If you have in the `else` only a comment, I would argue that the code needs to be fixed and the `else` be removed ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I studied more(please see the [source](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/google/googletest/+/refs/tags/release-1.8.0/googlemock/docs/CookBook.md#disallowing-unexpected-calls) and there is the best solution in this specific case.

If i want to verify if I it goes on else branch, I should just expect that the function from if to don't be called at all, using **.Times(0);**

```
EXPECT_CALL(MOCK_Member_name, another_function())  
         .Times(0);
```

For another detailed topics see: [googletest-release-1.8.0-googlemock](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/google/googletest/+/refs/tags/release-1.8.0/googlemock/docs/CookBook.md#creating-mock-classes)